# Fisrt user deleted, how to define new default admin?

Tags: permissions, sudo, users

when I installed my last Ubuntu machine with Jammy I had a typeO when I created the initial user account. Let's say I created "jod" but wanted to create "joe".

So when setup of the machine was done, I lived some time with my user being "jod", but after some time this annoyed me. So I created the new user "joe", added joe to the same groups as jod was and moved the content of /home/jod to /home/joe

Since this worked out fine, I deleted the user jod.

So I'm happy now?
Well not fully, since jod was the first user the system is a little confused now when it comes to "Privileged Access" with the GUI. Whenever a program needs root in the UI I have to enter the password for the user "root" I manually set after setup. Usually it would be the Password of the user "jod" since he was the first defined admin (sudoer) of the system. But since "jod" does not exist it falls back to "root".

So the question is, what do I need to do to get asked for the "joe" user password whenever a GUI App needs "Privileged Access"?

Since I added "joe" to the "sudo" and "admin" groups, I can work with sudo on the terminal just fine, so the issue are just graphical Apps within Gnome.

Thanks a lot for your help
Imker

BTW: I wounder if I would not be asked for any password if the user "root" would not have one set as it is the default with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

since there was no answer to this question I did some research and figured out how this works.

1. If a GUI application requires "Privileged Access" it talks with [polkit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html)
2. Plokit stores the configuration in `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/`

So I read through the configuration set in the system, and it look pretty reasonable to me

`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/50-localauthority.conf` tells

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:0
```

and `etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf` tells

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:sudo;unix-group:admin
```

That's it. So since `51-ubuntu-admin.conf` should overwrite `50-localauthority.conf` mebers of `admin` and `sudo` groups should be ask when "Privileged Access" is needed

But my user `joe` is member of `sudo` and I get ask for the `root` user, like configured in `50-localauthority.conf`

So I don't understand why it is not doing as it should.

But OK, I don't care and create my own overwrite `60-local-admin.conf` and make it look like:

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-user:joe
```

And vola. It works. The system asks for user `joe`s password whenever "Privileged Access" is needed since then.

I have now three files, and the last one is the one that counts.

Maybe some one else can use this as well

Bye